# Magnolia JCR get LinkedList Property Items

Tags: java, linked-list, jcr, magnolia, xpathnodeiterator

[image]

I am trying to retrieve the node 0's property - tag values, which is a linkedList object property I believe. as you can see it is [****,****]

I wish to retrieve the object value and store into a `List<String>` object
So I can get the each value out for late use, e.g

```
String idA = "542f74fd-bfaf-4377-854a-8e62082edc6c"; 
string idB = "39aab11f-243f-464c-ae6d-c1f069f17d6c";
```

My attampt is something like below:

```
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
tagList = componentNode.getProperties(node, "tags");
```

also tried this:

```
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
tagList = PropertyUtil.getProperty(node, "tags");
```

but none of them works.

Please suggest me with code sample.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they are called multi value properties in JCR and is supported via Arrays instead of Lists.

I haven't tested the code myself but I believe it'll work.
This should do the trick:

```
  Property property = node.getProperty("tags");     
  Value[] tags = property.getValues();
```

and then you can convert/wrap it to List if you really want to.

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: even better: `List<String> tags = info.magnolia.jcr.util.PropertyUtil.getValuesStringList(node.getProperty("tags").getValues());`